# only userform should be visible and not the excel

Tags: excel, vba

Please advise as to how can we show only `userform` and not excel behind it.

I used `application.visible = false` but it is hiding all the other excel.
I used `activatewindow.visible = false` but `userform` is not retrieving the data from excel.
I used `activatewindow.displayworkbooktabs=false` but it is not hiding the workbook.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.Visible = False
    UserForm1.Show vbModeless
End Sub
```

Don't forget to make Application visible before close

```
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    Application.Visible = True
End Sub
```

Comment: It is hiding all the other excel files. How can we avoid it

Comment: @GausShaikh check the ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlMinimized properties when you open the workbook. When you close the workbok you can set back the AxtiveWindow.WindowState = xlMaximized

Answer (score 0):

Write this to userform:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  Dim wCount  As Long
  Dim i       As Long

  wCount = Windows.Count
  For i = 1 To wCount
    Windows(i).Visible = True
  Next i

  Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
  Dim wCount  As Long
  Dim i       As Long

  wCount = Windows.Count
  For i = wCount To 1 Step -1
    Windows(i).Visible = False
  Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: will it hide all the excel file or only VBA excel file. Also, will I be able to retrieve the data from excel to userform

Comment: It is showing error as Method 'worksheets of object_Globel Failed

Comment: I have no errors.  In my workbook's worksheet1 has ActiveX commandbutton, in its event only one line: UserForm1.Show  In UserForm1 module has that code.